# ${10 \choose 4}+{11 \choose 4}+{12 \choose 4}+\cdots+{20 \choose 4}$ can be simplified as which of the following?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

${10 \choose 4}+{11 \choose 4}+{12 \choose 4}+\cdots+{20 \choose 4}$ can be simplified as ?

A. ${21 \choose 5}$

B. ${20 \choose 5}-{11 \choose 4}$

C. ${21 \choose 5}-{10 \choose 5}$

D. ${20 \choose 4}$

Please give me a hint. I'm unable to group the terms.
By brute force, I'm getting ${21 \choose 5}-{10 \choose 5}$

Comment: Brotip: You can use `{n \choose k}` for nCk, which will give the more readable (IMO) $${n \choose k}$$

Comment: Should the third term be *12* choose 4?

Comment: What would happen if you added $\binom{10}{5}$ to the beginning of the expression? A chain reaction...

Comment: Got it @alex.jordan
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**HINT 1 :**

Add $\dbinom{10}5$

**HINT 2:**

Make use of the identity $$\dbinom{n}{r} + \dbinom{n}{r-1} = \dbinom{n+1}{r}$$

Answer (score 2):

The same thing, combinatorially.  We want to choose $5$ positive integers from the first $21$. This can be done in $\binom{21}{5}$ ways.

We count the same thing in a different way. If the biggest chosen number is $21$, the rest can be chosen in $\binom{20}{4}$ ways. If the biggest is $20$, the rest can be chosen in $\binom{19}{4}$ ways. If the biggest is $19$, the rest can be chosen in $\binom{18}{4}$ ways. And so on, until if the biggest is $5$, the rest can be chosen in $\binom{4}{4}$ ways. 
We conclude that
$$\binom{20}{4}+\binom{19}{4}+\binom{18}{4}+\cdots+\binom{10}{4}+\binom{9}{4}+\cdots +\binom{4}{4}=\binom{21}{5}. \tag{$1$}$$
The same reasoning shows that
$$\binom{9}{4}+\binom{8}{4}+\cdots+\binom{4}{4}=\binom{10}{5}. \tag{$2$}$$

Now subtract $(2)$ from $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of [Vandermonde's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) says
$$
\sum_{j=m}^{n-k}\binom{n-j}{k}\binom{j}{m}=\binom{n+1}{k+m+1}\tag{1}
$$
Seting $k=0$ yields
$$
\sum_{j=m}^{n}\binom{j}{m}=\binom{n+1}{m+1}\tag{2}
$$
$(2)$ should be useful with $m=4$.

Answer (score 0):

What is the  problem in this solution?
If $S=\binom{10}{4} + \binom{11}{4} + \cdots + \binom{20}{4}$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
S&=& \left \{ \binom{4}{4} + \binom{5}{4} \cdots + \binom{20}{4}\right \} - \left \{\binom{4}{4} + \binom{5}{4} \cdots + \binom{9}{4}\right \} &=& \binom{21}{5} - \binom{10}{5}
\end{eqnarray}